# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation when referencing document.createElement

Tags: javascript, dom

If I can write

```
var x = window.alert;
x("Hello"); //This works as expected.
```

Why am I not being able to write the same for `document.createElement`.

```
var h = document.createElement;
h("div"); //This line throws error
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `h`, its context `this` refers to the wrong entry. You can fix this by binding it to `document`.

```
var h = document.createElement.bind(document)
```

`alert` can be called as-is, so the scope doesn't change when you alias it.

Comment: Why does the context stay the same for `alert`?

Comment: Because the default scope is `window`; `x` is the same as `window.x`; `h` is also `window.h` but needs to be `document.h`.

Comment: Brilliant. This really baffled me.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: most likely `alert` doesn't make use of `this`.

Comment: @Mathletics: not in strict mode. Seeing `foo()` as equivalent to `window.foo()` is not correct (in general).